# Print in Android using a printer with IP address and Port number

Tags: printing

My query is I have a printer connected to the Wifi and I am able to connect to that printer using the IP address of the printer but I am not able to print from that printer.

MY code:-

```
class MakeConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    String check = "NO";
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                Socket sock = null;
                PrintWriter oStream = null;
                try
                {
                     sock = new Socket(ipAddress, 9100);
                     oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
                    oStream.write("HI,test from Android Device");
                    check = "yes";
                    oStream.flush();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Logger.LogError(TAG, e.toString());
                    AppToast.showShortToast(mContext, e.toString());
                }
                finally {
                    oStream.close();
                    try {
                        sock.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Logger.LogError(TAG, check);
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}
```

where I am wrong?

Comment: pm dubey are fix .this error

Comment: @Amit Basliyal the error is not fixed yet. If you have any solution please suggest me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998772/e-pdfmanipulationservice-cannot-open-file-java-io-ioexception-not-create-docum