# E/PdfManipulationService: Cannot open file java.io.IOException: not create document. Error:

Tags: java, android, printing

hello people i am working on document printing app and first i am create a pdf file using ***iText*** **lib** and then i am connect the printer through ip address this is going well but when i am print(hp printer) the document then i got a error

like error below

```
 E/PdfManipulationService: Cannot open file
 java.io.IOException: not create document. Error:
 at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.nativeCreate(Native Method)
 at android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer.<init>(PdfRenderer.java:153)
 at com.android.printspooler.renderer.PdfManipulationService$PdfRendererImpl.openDocument(PdfManipulationService.java:92)
 at com.android.printspooler.renderer.IPdfRenderer$Stub.onTransact(IPdfRenderer.java:58)
 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

my code is

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button scan_Button;

private Handler mHandler;
private String ipAddress = "192.168.1.101";
PrintedPdfDocument mPdfDocument;
private int printItemCount;
private Appendable writtenPagesArray;
private int totalPages = 0;
String FILE;
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createPdfDocument();
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
    scan_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_Button);
    scan_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MakeConnection().execute();
            doPrint();
        }
    });
}

private void createPdfDocument() {


     FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + "/PDF/" + fileName+".pdf";
    Log.e("FILE", "=====>"+FILE);

    // Create New Blank Document
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    // Create Directory in External Storage
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/PDF");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Log.e("myDir", "=====>"+myDir);

    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

        // Open Document for Writting into document
        document.open();

        // User Define Method
        addMetaData(document);
        addTitlePage(document);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Close Document after writting all content
    document.close();

    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF File is Created. Location : " + FILE,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

// Set PDF document Properties
public void addMetaData(Document document)

{
    document.addTitle("RESUME");
    document.addSubject("Person Info");
    document.addKeywords("Personal, Education, Skills");
    document.addAuthor("TAG");
    document.addCreator("TAG");
}

public void addTitlePage(Document document) throws DocumentException {
    // Font Style for Document
    Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD);
    Font titleFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 22, Font.BOLD
            | Font.UNDERLINE, BaseColor.GRAY);
    Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.BOLD);
    Font normal = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12, Font.NORMAL);

    // Start New Paragraph
    Paragraph prHead = new Paragraph();
    // Set Font in this Paragraph
    prHead.setFont(titleFont);
    // Add item into Paragraph
    prHead.add("RESUME – Amit Basliyal\n");

    // Create Table into Document with 1 Row
    PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(1);
    // 100.0f mean width of table is same as Document size
    myTable.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);

    // Create New Cell into Table
    PdfPCell myCell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(""));
    myCell.setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);

    // Add Cell into Table
    myTable.addCell(myCell);

    prHead.setFont(catFont);
    prHead.add("\n testing\n");
    prHead.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

    // Add all above details into Document
    document.add(prHead);
    document.add(myTable);

    document.add(myTable);

    // Now Start another New Paragraph
    Paragraph prPersinalInfo = new Paragraph();
    prPersinalInfo.setFont(smallBold);
    prPersinalInfo.add("Address 1\n");
    prPersinalInfo.add("Address 1\n");
    prPersinalInfo.add("City: uuuu State: uuu\n");
    prPersinalInfo.add("Country: INDIA Zip Code: 000001\n");
    prPersinalInfo
            .add("Mobile: 0099999999Fax: 0101020101 Email: text@gmail.com \n");

    prPersinalInfo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);

    document.add(prPersinalInfo);
    document.add(myTable);

    document.add(myTable);

    Paragraph prProfile = new Paragraph();
    prProfile.setFont(smallBold);
    prProfile.add("\n \n Profile : \n ");
    prProfile.setFont(normal);
    prProfile
            .add("\nI am Mr. XYZ. I am Android Application Developer at TAG.");

    prProfile.setFont(smallBold);
    document.add(prProfile);

    // Create new Page in PDF
    document.newPage();
}

class MakeConnection extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String check = "NO";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.e("DoInBackGround", "==>");
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket(ipAddress, 9100);
            PrintWriter oStream = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            oStream.println("HI,test from Android Device");
            oStream.println("\n\n\n\f");
            oStream.close();
            sock.close();
       // doPrint();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.e("onPostExecute", "==>");
        //Logger.LogError(TAG, check);
        Log.e("onPostExecute", "==>" + check);
        //doPrint();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
}


private void doPrint() {
    // Get a PrintManager instance
    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

    // Set job name, which will be displayed in the print queue
    String jobName = this.FILE;
  //  Preferences.writeString(MainActivity.this,"filename",FILE);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("filename", FILE);
    editor.apply();

    // Start a print job, passing in a PrintDocumentAdapter implementation
    // to handle the generation of a print document
    printManager.print(jobName, new MyPrintDocumentAdapter(this),
            null);
   }
 }
```

**MyPrintDocumentAdapter.java**

```
public class MyPrintDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {

Activity activity;
PrintedPdfDocument mPdfDocument;
//Page[] writtenPagesArray;

public MyPrintDocumentAdapter(Activity activity)
{
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes,
                     PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                     CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                     LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

    // Create a new PdfDocument with the requested page attributes
    mPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(activity, newAttributes);

    // Respond to cancellation request
    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled() ) {
        callback.onLayoutCancelled();
        return;
    }

    // Compute the expected number of printed pages
    int pages = computePageCount(newAttributes);
    //  filename =Preferences.readString(context,"filename","");
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity);
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("filename", "default value");
    if (pages > 0) {
        // Return print information to print framework
        PrintDocumentInfo info = new PrintDocumentInfo
              // .Builder("print_output.pdf")
                .Builder(name)
                .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                .setPageCount(pages)
                .build();
        // Content layout reflow is complete
        callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
    } else {
        // Otherwise report an error to the print framework
        callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count calculation failed.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                    CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    // Write PDF document to file
    try {
        mPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(
                destination.getFileDescriptor()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
        return;
    } finally {
        mPdfDocument.close();
        mPdfDocument = null;
    }
    //PageRange[] writtenPages = computeWrittenPages();
    // Signal the print framework the document is complete
    callback.onWriteFinished(pages);


}

private int computePageCount(PrintAttributes printAttributes) {
    int itemsPerPage = 4; // default item count for portrait mode

    MediaSize pageSize = printAttributes.getMediaSize();
    if (!pageSize.isPortrait()) {
        // Six items per page in landscape orientation
        itemsPerPage = 6;
    }

    // Determine number of print items
    int printItemCount = 5; //getPrintItemCount();

    return (int) Math.ceil(printItemCount / itemsPerPage);
}

private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page) {
    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();

    // units are in points (1/72 of an inch)
    int titleBaseLine = 72;
    int leftMargin = 54;

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setTextSize(36);
    canvas.drawText("Test Title", leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);

    paint.setTextSize(11);
    canvas.drawText("Test paragraph", leftMargin, titleBaseLine + 25, paint);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 172, 172, paint);
   }

  }
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

For Hp printers you can use Hp-eprint by finding the email address of your
Hp printer and then you can use following code to send mail to your priner.As
You send the mail the attached document gets printed on your Hp Printer.

```
 private void openHpeprint() {
        File file = new File(folder + "/" + fileName);
        if (file.exists()) {
                Intent emailIntent = new Intent();
                emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             /*   Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);*/
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, mContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
                emailIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                emailIntent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                // set the type to 'email'
                emailIntent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
                emailIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
                String to[] = {"yourHpprinteremailaddress@Hpeprint.com"};
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
// the attachment
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
// the mail subject
                emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                try {
                    startActivity(emailIntent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Logger.LogError(TAG, "No Application Available to View Pdf");
                }

        }
    }
```